# Addressing the ith member of a std::tuple when i is not a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have the following function template:

```
template<typename T>
void mutate(T& t) { /*...*/ }
```

and I have the following class template:

```
template<typename... Args>
class Processor {
    std::tuple<Args...> tup;

    // call mutate on the ith tuple element
    void process(size_t i) {
        mutate(std::get<i>(tup)); // ERROR
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because the `i` parameter of `process` isn't a constant expression. (It can't be a constant expression, because `i` isn't known until runtime)

Without modifying the signature of `process` or `mutuate`, is there some way to efficiently make this work?  ie How can I change the implementation of `process` so that it calls `mutate` on the `i`th member of `tup`?

Comment: @Nicol I feel like both that question and those answers are fairly bad...

Comment: @Barry: There may be better ones, but that's the first one I found. It is very much a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'd rather write a good answer here and dupe-close that one - this question is _much_ better.

Comment: Plus this ones tagged C++17

Comment: Maybe consider using something other than `std::tuple` if that's a requirement?

Comment: @MarkRansom: Like what?

Comment: Your question doesn't show enough code to make a solid recommendation, but `std::vector` or `std::array` come to mind.

Comment: @MarkRansom: std::vector and std::array hold a sequence of objects of homogeneous type.  My application requires a sequence of objects of heterogeneous type.  Specifically these objects correspond to the data members of a reflected class type (the fields of a struct) that are undergoing serialization.

Comment: Is there a limit on `i`. For example is it in the range `0..10` etc. You could use a switch statement.

Comment: @MartinYork: Well, the limit on the number of template parameters in a template is 1024.  That would be fine as an upper bound.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I was thinking there is an application specific limit. But 1024 though doable is not a practical so a switch is probably not the way to go then :-)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Is there some user input that specifies `i`  at runtime or are you looping over all the values in a tuple?

Comment: @MartinYork: Neither, the input that effectively specifies i is received from the network, filesystem, shared memory or IPC at runtime.  It's to do with serialization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization  (or more precisely deserialization in this particular case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to take the runtime index and lift it into a constant expression. The easiest way to do that is to just use [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_with_indexni_f) which comes with a function just for this:

```
template<typename... Args>
class Processor {
    std::tuple<Args...> tup;

    // call mutate on the ith tuple element
    void process(size_t i) {
        mp_with_index<sizeof...(Args)>(i, [&](auto I){
            mutate(std::get<I>(tup));
        });
    }
}
```

What `mp_with_index` does is take a constant-expression for the max size (`sizeof...(Args)`) and the runtime size (`i`) and then invoke your callable (the lambda) with an integral constant that is the runtime size lifted up to a constant-expression.

---

This can be implemented yourself using `std::index_sequence` by building an array of function pointers and then invoking the correct one:

```
template <size_t... Is, typename F>
decltype(auto) mp_with_index(size_t i, F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using R = decltype(f(std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>{}));
    using P = R(*)(F&);
    static constexpr P fns[] = {
        +[](F& f) -> R { return f(std::integral_constant<size_t, Is>{}); }...
    };
    return fns[i](f);
}

template <size_t N, typename F>
decltype(auto) mp_with_index(size_t i, F f) {
    return mp_with_index(i, f, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

(note that the Boost.Mp11 implementation is better than this, this is just functionally correct).

Comment: In what way is the mp11 implementation superior to your implementation of `mp_with_index` given here?

Answer (score 5):

With some helper functions we can do it.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void mutate(T& t)
{
    std::cout << typeid(t).name() << "\n";
}

template<typename T, std::size_t... Seq>
void processes_each(int i, T& t, std::index_sequence<Seq...> const&)
{
    bool discard[] = {  false,
                        (i == Seq ? (mutate(std::get<Seq>(t)), true) : false) ...
                     };
    (void)discard;
}

template<typename... Args>
class Processes
{
    std::tuple<Args...> tup;

    public:
    void process(size_t i) {
        processes_each(i, tup, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>());
    }
};

int main()
{
    Processes<int, double>      p1;
    p1.process(0);
}
```

Comment: Nice. But the question is tagged C++17 so you can use template folding and simplify a little (avoiding `discard`) the body of `process_each()`; by example `((i == Seq ? (mutate(std::get<Seq>(t)), 0) : 0), ...); `

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun...

Waiting for C++20 (template lambda)

```
void process (std::size_t i)
 {
   [&]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
    { ((i == Is ? (mutate(std::get<Is>(tup)), 0) : 0), ...); }
     (std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
 }
```

in C++17 we can use a recursive generic lambda with `std::integral_constant`

```
   template <std::size_t I>
   using IC = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

   void process (std::size_t i)
    {
      auto l = [&](auto self, auto ic)
       { if constexpr ( ic < sizeof...(Args) )
            i == ic ? (mutate(std::get<ic>(tup)), 0)
                    : (self(self, IC<ic+1u>{}), 0); };

      l(l, IC<0u>{});
    }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void mutate (T & t)
 { std::cout << t << "\n"; }

template<typename... Args>
struct Processes
 {
   std::tuple<Args...> tup;

   template <std::size_t I>
   using IC = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;

   void process (std::size_t i)
    {
      auto l = [&](auto self, auto ic)
       { if constexpr ( ic < sizeof...(Args) )
            i == ic ? (mutate(std::get<ic>(tup)), 0)
                    : (self(self, IC<ic+1u>{}), 0); };

      l(l, IC<0u>{});
    }
};

int main()
 {
   Processes<char, int, long, long long>  p{{'0', 10, 200l, 3000ll}};

   p.process(2u);
 }
```